I can't compile the minecraft plugin
I'm working on a minecraft server, and I need to test one plugin for it. The plugin has sources on github, and I decided to use them (we are talking about the MMOEconomy plugin).
In order to compile the plugin, I tried to use the mvn install and mvn clean install commands, but in all cases the command line returned an error
[INFO] 3 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.718 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-05-14T15:47:35+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project MMOEconomy: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/Games/Minecraft/other/mmoeconomy-main/src/main/java/fr/phoenix/mmoeconomy/comp/item/ItemsAdderItem.java:[31,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getItemStack()
[ERROR]   location: class java.lang.Object
[ERROR] /D:/Games/Minecraft/other/mmoeconomy-main/src/main/java/fr/phoenix/mmoeconomy/comp/profiles/MMOEcoProfileDataModule.java:[19,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /D:/Games/Minecraft/other/mmoeconomy-main/src/main/java/fr/phoenix/mmoeconomy/comp/profiles/MMOEcoProfileDataModule.java:[29,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

P.S. The code from the ItemsAdderItem file may be useful.java is where this error comes from, so I'll leave all the code below
package fr.phoenix.mmoeconomy.comp.item;

import dev.lone.itemsadder.api.CustomBlock;
import dev.lone.itemsadder.api.CustomStack;
import dev.lone.itemsadder.api.ItemsAdder;
import io.lumine.mythic.lib.api.MMOLineConfig;
import org.apache.commons.lang.Validate;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

import java.util.List;

public class ItemsAdderItem implements EconomyItem {
    private final String id;

    public ItemsAdderItem(MMOLineConfig config) {
        config.validateKeys("id");
        this.id = config.getString("id");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ItemStack itemStack) {
        CustomStack stack = CustomStack.byItemStack(itemStack);
        if (stack == null) return false;
        return stack.getId().equals(id);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemStack getItemStack() {
        List<CustomStack> customStacks = ItemsAdder.getAllItems(id);
        Validate.isTrue(customStacks.size() > 0, "There isn't any ItemsAdder item associated to id: " + id);
        return ItemsAdder.getAllItems(id).get(0).getItemStack();
    }
}

to be honest, I do not even know how to approach this problem, because I do not understand java, but my task is to test this plugin before buying it on spigotmc

As you see from the maven output: ItemsAdderItem and MMOEcoProfileDataModule are erroneous.
For ItemsAdderItem: The class dev.lone.itemsadder.api.CustomStack seems to miss a getItemStack method. This may be caused by a wrong version definition inside the pom.xml (a Maven build file).
If you are not a developer, there probably is not much you can do about it. You should contact the entity that provided you with the Maven build files and report that they are broken and that a build from source is not possible.
